# Неизвестная ошибка при копировании файла

Tags: c++, winapi

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    BOOL b = CopyFile("E:\\DBFile.txt", "D:\\LogDB.txt", 0);
    if (!b) 
        cout << "Error: " << GetLastError() << endl;
    else 
        cout << "Ok" << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

---

Решил воспользоваться `GetLastError()`, убрал 2-ой слеш `\\` в путях файлов, в итоге получил вот такую ошибку: **123**

Поставил с 1-им слешом `\` получил ошибку: **2**

Как это расшифровывается?

Или же я не то получаю?

Должно оповестить что: `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`
[CopyFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa363851(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Нужно еще использовать функцию WinAPI `FormatMessage`, чтобы получить текстовое описание ошибки из ее числового кода.

Comment: Список с описанием кодов ошибок можно посмотреть [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms681381(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @alexolut, Ах ну да 2 - это и есть `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` - Я понял.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov, А как прикрутить `FormatMessage` к моему примеру?

Comment: @GooliveR, моих сил в C++ для выполнения этого "на лету" недостаточно. `FormatMessage` принимает параметром указатель на буфер, а так же допустимый размер строки. Если размер буфера слишком мал, то, наверное, надо каким-то специфичным для C++ способом вызывать еще какую-то ошибку.

Comment: Решил не мучиться и сделал так: `GetLastError() == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

Comment: То что Вы оформили как обновление вопроса следовало бы оформить самостоятельным ответом.

Comment: @alexolut, Да не вопрос ))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Убирать вторые бэкслеши не стоило, ибо `\` имеет особый смысл в строковых литералах C/C++ - символ, идущий за ним, тогда трактуется специальным образом; например, `\n` - символ новой строки. Чтобы получить в строке обычный `\`, нужно написать `\\`:

```
cout << "\\\n";
```

выведет на экран `\` и перейдет на новую строку.

А если посмотреть, то в заголовочных файлах Windows SDK можно найти

```
#define ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND        2
#define ERROR_INVALID_NAME        123
```

Так что вы и получили то, что должны были.

Comment: Уже нашёл свои ошибки )) Буду знать терь.

Answer (score 1):

Добавил по рекомендациям [@Alexander Zonov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/239133/alexander-zonov),  функцию `FormatMessage`

В итоге всё отобразилось как нужно =)

```
#define BUFSIZE 256

BOOL b = CopyFile("E:\\DBFile.txt", "D:\\LogDB.txt", 0);

DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
char err[BUFSIZE];
FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,NULL,lastError,MAKELANGID
(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), err, 255, NULL);

if (!b) 
    cout << "Error: " << err << endl;
else 
    std::cout << "File was copied" << std::endl;
```